# How would I check if a date is between two dates and return a number based on the response in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to have a system in place that means that I can have a table of 5 columns and x rows such that, in a different sheet, I can check whether the date is between two weeks, and return the correct value based on the check. ie if the date was between 2 and 3 weeks ago return the first number, if between 4 and 5 weeks, second number, 6 and 7 weeks, 3rd number, 8 weeks, 4th number. If it is more than 9 weeks ago it should not return a number for that row.

I want it to be able to sum up payments as well. So if there are multiple payments in a week, return the sum of those payments.
I could manually get it to look at five rows, but I really don't want to do that as it would get messy if I needed to increase it.

I was thinking along the lines of a for loop that first checked if there was a description for the row, and then if there was, run the program.

[image: excel spreadsheet]

Comment: I have a question. Do you have a background in VBA (know how to code a bit)? Are you asking so someone can help in building the logic, or do you want someone to write the entire code?

Answer (score 0):

I created a code that should do most of the things you need (The code is below). Copy-paste it to a module and change what needs to be changed, such as the location of the data and the output location. I placed comments to help you through the code.

Modifying/adding features to the code is your task ;D.
Note I read your profile, and you mentioned that you are interested in learning VBA. I hugely advise doing so, for it is handy and straightforward.

Below is a snip showing how the result of running the code. Hope this help

[image]

**The code is below here**

If you are a beginner in VBA, you might be overwhelmed at the code, because I am using "arrays/ranges" rather than "cells". While "cells" is simpler to understand and usually is taught at the beginning of VBA learning. The "arrays/ranges" are better because they are faster and more efficient when coding advanced programs. So if you are genuinely planning to learn VBA, I advise you to start using/learning about "arrays/ranges" in VBA.

```
Sub Main()


    Dim DataLocation As Range

    Set DataLocation = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") '' Set this to the location of you data

    Dim DataArray As Variant
    DataArray = DataLocation.CurrentRegion


    Dim WeeksArray As Variant '' this will store the date, when was the payment in weeks, the payment value, the payment index/column used
    ReDim WeeksArray(1 To UBound(DataArray, 1), 1 To 4) '' This to resize the array to match the number of data point.

    WeeksArray(1, 1) = "Date"
    WeeksArray(1, 2) = "Weeks Ago"
    WeeksArray(1, 3) = "Payment"
    WeeksArray(1, 4) = "Payment Column Used"

    Dim i As Long
    Dim PaymentDate As Date
    Dim WeeksAgo As String
    Dim PaymentIndex As Long
    Dim PaymentValue As Variant
    For i = (LBound(DataArray, 1) + 1) To UBound(DataArray, 1) '' The +1 at the start is because the first record in the DaraArray is the header (Date, Pay1, and etc)

        PaymentDate = DataArray(i, 1)

        WeeksArray(i, 1) = PaymentDate
        WeeksAgo = HowManyWeeksAgo(PaymentDate)
        WeeksArray(i, 2) = WeeksAgo

        PaymentIndex = PaymentToUse(WeeksAgo)
        If PaymentIndex > 0 Then
            PaymentValue = DataArray(i, PaymentIndex + 1) ''' The +1 is because the the first column is the date column
        Else
            PaymentValue = ""
        End If

        WeeksArray(i, 3) = PaymentValue
        WeeksArray(i, 4) = PaymentIndex

    Next i

    Dim OutputLocation As Range
    Set OutputLocation = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K1") ''' Change this Location to where you want to output the result

    Set OutputLocation = OutputLocation.Resize(UBound(WeeksArray, 1), 4)

    OutputLocation = WeeksArray

End Sub

'''''''Change The function below to suit your needs/conditions for the weeks
Function HowManyWeeksAgo(PaymentDate As Date) As String

    Dim DaysPast As Long

    DaysPast = Date - PaymentDate

    If DaysPast < 7 Then
        HowManyWeeksAgo = "Less Than 1 week"
    ElseIf DaysPast >= 7 And DaysPast < 14 Then
        HowManyWeeksAgo = "1 to 2 weeks"
    ElseIf DaysPast >= 14 And DaysPast < 21 Then
        HowManyWeeksAgo = "2 to 3 weeks"
    ElseIf DaysPast >= 21 And DaysPast < 28 Then
        HowManyWeeksAgo = "3 to 4 weeks"
    ElseIf DaysPast >= 28 And DaysPast < 35 Then
        HowManyWeeksAgo = "4 to 5 weeks"
    Else
        HowManyWeeksAgo = "More than 5 weeks"
    End If

End Function

''''''' Change the function below to suit your needs/conditions for which payment to use based on the week
Function PaymentToUse(WeeksAgo As String) As Long
    If WeeksAgo = "Less Than 1 week" Then
        PaymentToUse = 1
    ElseIf WeeksAgo = "1 to 2 weeks" Then
        PaymentToUse = 2
    ElseIf WeeksAgo = "2 to 3 weeks" Then
        PaymentToUse = 3
    ElseIf WeeksAgo = "3 to 4 weeks" Then
        PaymentToUse = 4
    ElseIf WeeksAgo = "4 to 5 weeks" Then
        PaymentToUse = 5
    Else
        PaymentToUse = 0
    End If
End Function
```